# Variable scope with dictionaries

Tags: python

This executes without error:

```
def myfunction():
    global a_dict
    a_dict['s'] = 'whatevs'
    b_dict['s'] = 'lalala'
    a_dict = b_dict

a_dict = {'s':[], 'm':[]}
b_dict = {'s':[], 'm':[]}
myfunction()
```

Why does this not throw an error without also adding `global b_dict` to the function - as I'm writing to both dictionaries?

It sure does if I comment out the `global a_dict` ("'a_dict' referenced before assignment") - as I would expect.

Comment: You can reduce your chances of getting downvoted by spelling "I" correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You only need `global foo` when you want to *assign* to the global name `foo`. You are not assigning to `b_dict`; you are assigning to one of its *keys*, equivalent to `b_dict.__setitem__('s', 'lalala')`. Both uses of `b_dict` treat it as a free variable, since there is no local variable named `b_dict` defined.

The value of a free variable is taken from the closest enclosing scope (in this case, the global scope) where it is defined.

Answer (score 0):

The fact of declaring a variable as global in a function allows you to use a variable outside that function. If there is no variable b declared inside it, Python is going to assume it is a global variable declared before the function call.